# Python argparse with choices

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to run my python program from the command line with some options. E.g. say my program has 4 modes, and I want it to use mode 2 by giving it the following arguments:

```
$ python main.py --mode 2
```

(And similarly for modes 1, 3, 4). How can I achieve this using argparse?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PROJECT_NAME')
parser.add_argument(
    '--mode', '-m',
    help='Set mode',
    default=1,
    type=int,
    choices=[1,2,3,4],
)
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.mode)
```

For a complete list of the options available visit the docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Update:

Added the suggestions from MaLiN2223's comment

Comment: Thank you! What is the '-m' part doing here?

Comment: I would also add `type=int` in the name of 'fail early' principle (and so you don't have to do it yourself). Maybe also `choices=[1,2,3,4]` ?

Comment: just a optional shorthand so you can write `python main.py -m 2`

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question of how to limit to four choices. To be complete, this needs to include the comment from @MaLiN2223.